# Question Deleted By OP

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-questions

I have answer a [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57270634/spring-boot-ajax-post-request-issue) which was asked by [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10012584/mutlu).

There was a small mistake done by him in making a request. So I have suggested the right way to make a request and the answer which he was looking for has been solved.

After changing this he had a *new issue with CORS Policy which doesn't relate with Original Context* when the question has been asked. Although I successfully give a solution for it and issue for CORS has been solved. So I polity told him to accept and upvote the answer if it was helpful to him.

After that, he has asked the new issue in the same question so *I suggest him to ask a new question and provided a hint of how he can solve the latest issue.* As asking and updating question for multiple issues in the **same question (here 3 different issues)** change the context of original Issue/Post and SO community also suggest that to avoid asking multiple questions.

After that, I left the discussion, he has deleted the question which has an answer (which could solve an issue for future people who are looking for the same issue) which might deserve to be *accepted-/upvoted*. I have spent my time to solves someone's issue which doesn't receive a proper response from OP and it was quite *discouraging* for me to answer the question. ***Does deleting the question after getting a solution is right?*** How can I handle such a situation or I have done something wrong?

**UPDATE**

OP has also deleted another question we have asked for the last issue. As I know the question there was not a typo or can be flagged as low quality. So anyone who has made an effort to answer the question is in vain [New Deleted Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57272939/ajax-post-request-issue-about-my-spring-boot-rest-api)

Now I will take care of Whom to answer, but I found that SO has answered to **[71%](https://stackexchange.com/sites#)** questions till now. So the remaining 29% are answered. If we consider 10% is a complex issue (or OP can share all details according to company policy). Then the remaining 19% is a low-quality question (might be removed) which we haven't answer them. Currently, I don't have any analytic tools, maybe I am making a wrong assumption.

**Original Question Context: Asking for making a POST request from AJAX**
[image]

**Context Chanegd to CORS Issue:** 
[image]

**3rd Issue in the same Question** 
[image]

Provided a hint to solve the latest issue
[image]

Comment: The OP can delete their own question as long as there are no upvoted or accepted answers. It's probably a good idea to follow the advice on [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and only answer good questions. CORS issues have a long and storied history on Stack Overflow, so I expect it was likely a duplicate... (since it is deleted I can't confirm).

Comment: @HereticMonkey, Moderators can see the post with its history. The original question has nothing to do with CORS. The original context was asking for making a POST request using Ajax to Spring Boot.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have added the images for the reference

Comment: Comment and then flag/vote to close as a typo.  You don't waste your time or theirs and everyone wins.  Yeah, you don't get rep, but, at least in my opinion, site quality > rep.

Answer (score 19):

How is this going to be a useful question to others?  The problem is just a simple typo in a URL, and yet the question contains several hundreds of lines of irrelevant code, and the question just states that what the code is and says it's not working, without even any description of what about it isn't working.

There is no value here for why the question should be kept around.  Frankly it's worth deleting by us even if the author didn't do us the favor of deleting it themselves.

Comment: then the time I have spent to answer this question is worthless or we should not answer that kind of questions? Even from the question which he has asked I can't see much effort by OP to solve an issue. new Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57272939/ajax-post-request-issue-about-my-spring-boot-rest-api

Comment: @PatelRomil You are correct that you should not be answering low quality questions that merit closure or even deletion.

Comment: @PatelRomil Keep in mind that if your answer was upvoted, OP wouldn't have been able to delete the question.

Comment: @jhpratt OP has deleted the question approx within 1 hour, might OP has deleted it because I was told him to ask a new question for a different issue

Comment: OP has also deleted the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57272939/ajax-post-request-issue-about-my-spring-boot-rest-api